# I want the to load all the data at once at some specific condition in my page using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this jquery function.It is working fine and bringing the data when i click at any particular character. If i click "A" then it bring all the places starting with A.But i want to load all the countries at once irrespective of any character click if i write some condition.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    alert(1);
    //  Listen for Click
    $(".serving-nav a").click(function (e) {

        //  Get the Character
        var theChar = $(this).data('alpha');

        //  Hide Others
        $(this).parent().find('a').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
        $(".serving-data .serving-nav-data").stop(true, true).slideUp(500);

        //  Show the Related
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(".serving-data .serving-nav-data[data-alpha='" + theChar + "']").stop(true, true).slideDown(500);

        //  Prevent Default
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    //  Trigger Click on Active One
    $(".serving-nav a.active").click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'd just do:

```
$(".serving-data .serving-nav-data').show();
```

Or, if you still want them animated:

```
$(".serving-data .serving-nav-data').stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
```

Basically, if you don't want to select based on the `data-alpha` property, just don't include that selector.